# 4 Pesukim between Shir Hama'alos (or Al Naharos Bovel) and Birkas Hamazon

Tags: sources-mekorot, bentching, artscroll

In all Artscroll versions of Birkas Hamazon, you will find the 4 pesukim of Tehilas Hashem, Va'anachnu, Hodu laShem and Mi Y'maleil between Shir Hama'alos or Al Naharos Bovel and zimun.

What is the source for saying these pesukim?